# Insert INTO query not working for one method but working for another

Tags: java, database, ms-access

I have two method one is working and other's not working for insert query

```
// this one fails
public void product(String product, String quantity, String price,
        String date) throws SQLException {
    try {       
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO product (productn,quantity,price,date) VALUES ('" +       product + "','" + quantity + "','" + price + "','" + date + "')");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

// this one works
public void customer(String name, String q, String p, String pro)
        throws SQLException {
    try {
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO Customer (name,price,product,quantity) VALUES ('" + name  + "','" + q + "','" + p + "','" + pro + "')");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("problem in Customer insert !");
    }
}
```

one method which is working fine mean it insert data into the table but the other is giving the following error:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement
```

Comment: please paste the stacktrace

Comment: Please post the StackTrace

Comment: Not working means what? are you getting any exception? if yes, post stacktrace.

Comment: Why is not working? any error message?

Comment: here is the error
 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: Is this the exact code you are using, If not please paste the complete stack trace

Comment: Have you taken the connection?

Comment: Could you update your question pasting the error and the stacktrace?

Comment: there is no exception but there is ODBC Microsoft Access Driver error which is "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."

Comment: I am surprised that either of them work. You are using [reserved words](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738) and have used text data type for all values regardless of the data type of the fields.

Comment: @SashiKant yes i have taken the connection which is working fine for one function

Comment: Could you print that sql statement using System.out.println() and tell us what you got?

Comment: @Remou i took all strings because that was giving problem for the integer and i used just one data type to make it simple so it could work

Comment: @PradeepSimha see 
INSERT INTO product (productn,quantity,price,date) VALUES ('Product 1','23','232','212')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO product ([productn],[quantity],[price],[date]) VALUES ('" + product + "','" + quantity + "','" + price + "','" + date + "')
```

And let me know if it works

Comment: Problem was you were using date, which was a reserved word so you need to escape with [ ]

Answer (score 2):

You'll have more chance to do it in this way, like that you could check better the integrity of the values.

```
private static final String insert = "INSERT INTO product (productn,quantity,price,date) VALUES ('"+?+"','"+?+"','"+?+"','"+?+"')";



statement.clearParameters();

statement.set"Type_of_the_value"(1, productn) ;

statement.set"Type_of_the_value"(2, quantity) ;

statement.set"Type_of_the_value"(3, price) ;

statement.set"Type_of_the_value"(4, date) ;

statement.executeUpdate() ;
```